# Delphi XE5 - Android - TMemIniFile behaves unusual

Tags: android, windows, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have written some code:

```
MnemonicList := TStringList.Create();

{$IFDEF Android}
  IniPath := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, ADefaultLanguage + '.ini');  { Internal }
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF Win32}
  IniPath := TPath.Combine(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), 'Lang\' + ADefaultLanguage + '.ini');
{$ENDIF}

if FileExists(IniPath) then
begin
 MemIniFile := TMemIniFile.Create(IniPath);
 ShowMessage(IniPath);

 MemIniFile.ReadSections(MnemonicList);
 ShowMessage(IntToStr(MnemonicList.Count));
end;
```

The second ShowMessage() results with 4 when runs on Windows and 0 when runs on Android... File is populated correctly and FileExists(IniPath) gives True also on Android. I can open files on Android and Windows in editor as well.
Are there any differences on TMemIniFile on Android?

Comment: It's kind of hard to say with only what you've posted, but there are you sure the INI file is populated on Android? Keep in mind each time you deploy your application to your device the storage is wiped clean. Also, how are you getting your path? On Android it should be something like this `TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'mysettings.ini'`

Comment: Yes, it's OK. Files are in the filesystem... I edited question now.

Comment: Your path setup looks good to me. I use TMemINIFile in a project on Android and I haven't had any problems. You could try creating a separate project and just try a very simple Read/Write command.

Comment: IniPath is '/data/data/<name>/files/pl.ini'  I can't get there with file manager but FileExists results with True

Comment: AssignFile(TempFile, IniPath); Reset(TempFile); ReadLn(TempFile, TempString);   ... works perfect!

Comment: What happens if you try read an individual value instead of a section?  Not sure why that would be different, but I haven't ReadSections.

Comment: solved... take a look at answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with INI file **characters encoding**. When I changed to UTF-8 w/o BOM it started to work.